# Can I convert a .swf file to an image format?

Tags: java, flash, image-processing, coldfusion

I need to take a .swf Flash file, ideally from a URL (but I can read the file from disk also) and create an image preview of it (png, gif or jpeg is fine).

I am using Adobe Coldfusion 8 so I'm looking for a Java solution. I need to get the first frame of the Flash movie only.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: I need to do this on the server in Java/CF at runtime - it's got to be automatic - I'm not looking for screen-grab software! :)

Answer (score 3):

Is this running in a web browser?  Or standalone - actually, either works.  Simply get it to the point you want, and take a screenshot (Print Screen).  That'll giev you an image you can paste into your image app of choice.

**IF** however you're wanting to code it, you'll need to probably want to try this freeware toolkit:

http://bytescout.com/swftoimage_swf_to_jpg.html

which allows you to take a flash file and convert the first frame to your image type of choice :)

Comment: This has to be done at runtime via Java. This tool doesn't appear to satisfy that.

Comment: You can call out to the OS and execute the app on it, surely? Either interface or run it as a standalone app?

Answer (score 3):

Try [swftools](http://www.swftools.org). It has utility called swfrender which can export frames into images. And it is open source :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but I think you can't without some tricky tools because SWF is a compiled flash program.

UPD: but there are some swf2flv converters, maybe u can use them. It is easier to make a preview from flv format.

UPD 2: I see several answers that recommends you to open it in a browser and make a print screen. If you really want to do this, look at [JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/index.jsf).

Comment: It still loads data into memory when it runs, which means it can be accessed, one way or another ;)

Answer (score 0):

AS3 has the capability to store the pixels that represent the entire screen into a BitmapData object, pass that to a JPG/PNG encoder, and post it to the server. There is a document on Adobe's devnet [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/saving_flash_graphics.html) that explains how the ActionScript works and what is needed with regard to PHP, shouldn't be hard to translate to CF.

Comment: AS3 is no good, I need to get this done on the server, in Java. This solution requires coding in AS3 and the final image is sent to a server for display.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

here's an .net article:

http://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/screenshot-of-webpage-with-aspnet-AID398.aspx

basically you create a webpage showing the .swf flash file.

remember to call iecapt.exe including the command line argument --delay=10000 to give the ie activex control 10sec to load the .swf

Answer (score -2):

Probably not what you're looking for but... Alt+Print Screen would work.. :)

More seriously.. find something that can render flash (IE ActiveX control?) and capture the buffer it renders.